# how do i specify a filename when unloading using redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am attempting to specify the file name when unloading data to an  s3 folder, the below example will only create the filename "customer" where as i want one called "customer_ba" can someone please advise?

```
UNLOAD ('select * from (select * from mydb.customer LIMIT 2147483647);') TO 's3://je-s3- bp-00/results/myfolder/customer/delete' WITH  CREDENTIALS AS 'aws_access_key_id=***********;aws_secret_access_key=*****' DELIMITER AS '|'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the **customer** really a file? It should be a directory with file names beginning with **delete** (as in your command).

Answer (score 0):

If your s3 bucket is named "s3://je-s3- bp-00/results/myfolder/customer/", the name in your question will create a file name with prefix "delete_000[1..n]" depending on the slices you have.